# Will QGIS 2.99 and QGIS 3.0 always be the same?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

For a dev, QGIS 2.99.0-Master is the next QGIS version which will be released.

that why http://doc.qgis.org/api/index.html is so important to make the bridge.

But it is simple as that ?

What will become 2.99 when QGIS 3 will be released ?
Is the dev version of QGIS 3.x will be named QGIS 3.99.0-Master ?

Comment: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html should answer your question.

Comment: 2.99 version was a special number. Maybe the day the dev team decides to go for QGIS 4 there will be a 3.99, but before that, the usual numbering will go on (odd for dev, even for release)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 3.0 is released, the dev version will be called 3.1, and the next release will be 3.2.

As AndreJ mentioned, the most recent roadmap is published on the QGIS website https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html

Comment: when will Qgis 3.0 be available on the the repository "http://qgis.org/debian"? On 2017-12-08? What exactly does it mean "Repo" and "Latest"  in the release table?

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico Please open a new thread if you have a new question. This way, the information will be more discoverable by future readers.